# How to storage a directory file names in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get the names of all audio files from my /assets/audio folder to dynamically create sound buttons. Right now I have an array in which I manually typed the name of all the files. The idea is to automatically get the names when I add new files to the project and not to add them manually to the array.

I have been looking for quite some time already, but I have not come to any solution that suits for my situation.
I am trying to develop a simple Android app, no server, no back-end, it is a soundboard. But a lot of the solutions to my question says that I need to use back-end to do this. More specifically, use `fs`, like this:

```
const testFolder = './tests/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
});
```

But i get this error that I have not found a solution:

```
[ng] Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

Is there a simple way to read directory files and storage the names in an Array?

My apologies, I am still learning and there are a lot of things i do not know how to look for properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably circumvent locked (or other inaccesible) files with a `try/catch`

```
fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
  try { 
    console.log(file);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('cannot read file', e);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response, but you can use this little function to do this

```
    function importAll(r) {
        return r.keys().map(r);
    }
    const testFolder = importAll(
        require.context("./tests/", false, /*/)
    );
```

I used this with webpack in a react project, so I don't know how it works without webpack bundling your data beforehand, but the data returned from `require` doesn't look like an array (tbh i don't know what it is). When you map it it returns an array though so I think it should work in your case as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have already did ```npm install``` in multiple occasions, but it did not resolved the error :/
Also, I am using windows 10.